# OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spacy

I'm trying to extract locations from text using Spacy in Google Colab:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
```

Returns:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will get a message saying---**

✔ Download and installation successful

You can now load the package via spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

Answer (score 2):

**For Google Collab: **

```
import spacy.cli

spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_lg")
```

**You will get a message saying--**

✔ Download and installation successful

You can now load the package via spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the model before you use it. Please refer to the [quickstart](https://spacy.io/usage).

```
spacy download en_core_web_lg
```